# #+BIND and org-mode asynchronous exporting document

Tags: org-export, beamer, async

Let's say I have the following org-file:

```
#+TITLE: Presentation title
#+BIND: org-beamer-outline-frame-title "My own title"

#+LATEX_CLASS: beamer

* Section 1
** Slide 1
```

When I export this document in sync mode (`org-beamer-export-to-pdf nil`)
it works ok.

But exporting in asynchronous mode throws
`` Process `org-export-process` exited abnormally ``.

If I comment out the line with `#+BIND` command I can export
in both modes.

I need to mention that according to these sources
[1](https://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/emacs-orgmode/2016-02/msg00276.html),
[2](https://superuser.com/questions/738492/org-mode-8-async-export-process-fails),
[3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41964712/how-does-bind-really-works/42012392#42012392)
I created my `async_init.el` with the following content:

```
(require 'package)
(setq package-enable-at-startup nil)
(package-initialize)

(require 'org) 
(require 'ox)
(require 'cl)
(require 'ox-beamer)
(setq org-export-allow-bind-keywords t)
(setq org-export-async-debug t)
```

and added the following to my `init.el`:

```
(setq org-export-in-background t)
(setq org-export-async-init-file (expand-file-name "~/.emacs.d/myarch/async_init.el"))
```

What am I missing to have async export working with `#+BIND`?

I found several threads with similar issue
[4](https://www.reddit.com/r/emacs/comments/e4zz89/orgbeamerexporttopdf_async_returns_unknown_nil/)
[5](https://list.orgmode.org/orgmode/8735bh65jb.fsf@localhost/)
[6](https://emacs-stackexchange-com.translate.goog/questions/69128/setting-variables-for-async-org-export?_x_tr_sl=en&_x_tr_tl=pl&_x_tr_hl=pl&_x_tr_pto=sc)
but they give (me) no clue on what to do to solve the problem...

Comment: You need to enable `org-async-debug` in your `init.el` i.e. in your Emacs: that's where you start the async process. Doing it in `async-init.el` doesn't help: you are not starting any async process from the spawned Emacs.

Answer (score 0):

You are probably missing an initialization. Async is done by spawning a new Emacs process with a special initialization file (specified by `org-export-async-init-file`). If that file is incomplete in any way, the new Emacs process will not start and you will get the dreaded error you encounter.

`org-export-async-start` is the function that is called when you export with async mode enabled. When it starts the new process, it creates a proc buffer for it with:

```el
    ...
    (proc-buffer (generate-new-buffer-name "*Org Export Process*"))
    ...
```

If the process fails, then it adds the buffer to a stack of such buffers created for async processes:

```el
  (org-export-add-to-stack proc-buffer nil p)
```

and the buffer sticks around so you can examine it, even without setting `org-export-async-debug` (it is normally deleted on successful exit, but it is kept around even in that case if `org-export-async-debug` is set).

The stack is stored in `org-export-stack-contents` so you can switch to the first buffer in the stack with `M-: (pop-to-buffer (car org-export-stack-contents))`, but since the buffer has a special name (`*Org Export Process*` possibly followed by a `<N>` for some number `N` if you have more than one such failed process, you can just use `C-x b` to switch to the buffer. With `org-export-async-debug` set, the temporary file is also kept around: you can find it under `/tmp/org-export-process<mumble>` where `<mumble>` is some jumble of characters to disambiguate this temp file from others.

The buffer and the temp file should allow you to debug the problem. When I tried your example locally (without any `org-export-async-init-file`), the buffer showed me this:

```
Debugger entered--Lisp error: (file-missing "Cannot open load file" "No such file or directory" "auctex-autoloads")
  load("auctex-autoloads")
  load-library("auctex-autoloads")
  eval-buffer(#<buffer  *load*-199044> nil "/home/nick/elisp/config/auctex-config.el" nil t)  ; Reading at buffer position 126
  load-with-code-conversion("/home/nick/elisp/config/auctex-config.el" "/home/nick/elisp/config/auctex-config.el" nil t)
  require(auctex-config)
  (if (experimental-enabled) (require 'auctex-config))
  eval-buffer(#<buffer  *load*> nil "/home/nick/.config/emacs/init.el" nil t)  ; Reading at buffer position 9932
  load-with-code-conversion("/home/nick/.config/emacs/init.el" "/home/nick/.config/emacs/init.el" nil t)
  load("/home/nick/.config/emacs/init.el" nil t)
  command-line-1(("-l" "/home/nick/.config/emacs/init.el" "-l" "/tmp/org-export-processA3Ppqe"))
```

so I would need to add some things to the `load-path` in the init file.

Hope this helps you debug the problem.

---

FWIW, when I try with your `async-init.el` and your `init.el` and your example, the async export succeeds, including the effect of `#+BIND`. I moved the setting of `org-export-async-debug` from the first to the second, although that does not matter to the success or failure: however it needs to be in `init.el` in order to allow you to debug problems - as mentioned in the comment, putting in `async-init.el` is ineffective.

Comment: Thank you for your thorough answer. In the end it turned out that my MWE example hadn't worked because of typo in `(setq org-export-allow-bind-keywords t)`. As it comes to the original problem, from which I started digging...  I did as you suggested, and moved `(setq org-export-async-debug t)` to `init.el`. Now, Emacs spits out tons of lines in `*Org Export Process*` buffer which I'm going to analyse soon.

Comment: In the meanwhile I also "rediscovered" a way to circumvent problems with `#BIND`. You can always use [file variables list](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Specifying-File-Variables.html). Personally, I feel more confident with them....

Comment: The difference is the lifetime of the variable: file variables are active when the buffer is created and go away when the buffer is killed; `#+BIND: ` settings are active only during export of the file.  Although I cannot come up with a simple (or even complicated) example at this point, it's conceivable that you might want a different value for a variable when exporting but you don't want that variable to be active while e.g. editing the buffer.